# Store a formated printed value in a new variable

Tags: c, sha256

In a encryption function (sha256) I have this code for print the final result:

```
void print_hash(unsigned char hash[]) 
   {
       int idx;
       for (idx=0; idx < 32; idx++)
          printf("%02x",hash[idx]);
       printf("\n");
    }
```

when hash enter in the function is something like:

```
/A�`�}#.�O0�T����@�}N�?�#=\&@
```

Then, with the loop, I get in this in the console

```
182f419060f17d2319132eb94f30b7548d81c0c740977d044ef1edbb9b97233d
```

I want to know HOW TO STORE that final value in console in a variable.
I have readed something about sscanf, but can you help me?

Comment: The function you should read about it `sprintf`.

Comment: ... *and* `strcat`. Or read about *pointer arithmetic*.

Comment: SHA256 is not encryption, it is a one-way hash function, the original data can not be recovered from the resulting hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in an array (passed in parameter through a pointer) using `sprintf`:

```
void print_hash(unsigned char hash[], unsigned char output[])
{
    int idx;
    for (idx = 0; idx < 32; idx++)
        sprintf(&output[2 * idx], "%02x", hash[idx]);
}
```

Be sure to reserve an extra byte for the null-terminator in `output` (i.e., `char output[2 * 32 + 1]`).

Comment: You need to increment `output` in the loop body, too, or the output will be just the final element.

Comment: @ouah That should be `&output[2*idx]`, assuming each loop iteration appends 2 characters.

Comment: Try `char *result = output; result += sprintf(result, "%02x", hash[idx]);`

Comment: Thanks guys. Can anybody tell me why my question has -1 points? :c

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf`, this function stores its output (which is equivalent to what `printf` writes to the console) in a string buffer. An example of how to use it in your case:

```
char buffer[65]; //Make this buffer large enough for the string and a nul terminator
for(int idx = 0; idx < 32; ++idx)
{
    sprintf(&buffer[2*idx], "%02x", hash[idx]); //Write to the correct position in the buffer
}
```

The terminating nul character is automatically appened by `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also avoid using `sprintf()` and make a more efficient funcion like this

```
void
hash2digest(char *result, const char *const hash, size_t length)
{
    const char *characters = "0123456789abcdef";
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        result[2 * i] = characters[(hash[i] >> 0x04) & 0x0F];
        result[2 * i + 1] = characters[hash[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    result[2 * length] = '\0';    
}
```

Note that you can call it from wherever you want just like this (assuming `hash` is already declared and defined)

```
char digest[65];
hash2digest(digest, hash, 32);
```

This in turn can be reused for `SHA1` for example, like this

```
char digest[41];
hash2digest(digest, hash, 20);
```

And using dynamic memory allocation

```
char *
hash2digest(const char *const hash, size_t length)
{
    const char *characters = "0123456789abcdef";
    char *result;
    result = malloc(2 * length + 1);
    if (result == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i)
    {
        result[2 * i] = characters[(hash[i] >> 0x04) & 0x0F];
        result[2 * i + 1] = characters[hash[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    result[2 * length] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```